# Need help to config a CDN

Tags: configuration, cdn, azure-cdn, google-cdn

Hello I want to configure a CDN to reduce the loading time of my website.

Amenitiz the company to which I pay the monthly payments for my website: hotelverdon.com redirects me to you the company which hosts my site to set up this.

I am open to any offer to improve the loading speed of my website, especially on mobile.

Sincerely, Mr Caron Anthony

Answer (score 0):

If you can host your application in Azure using Azure App service, you can map your custom domain to the azure web application.

You can create Azure CDN profile and create an endpoint. You can add your custom domain to CDN profile. Then you can configure your CDN to your web application.

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/cdn/cdn-add-to-web-app